# package javafx.util does not exist

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, javafx-11

I am running java version 11.0.2 on a Mac.  WHen I compiled a java file that imports `javafx.util.pair` I got an `error: package javafx.util does not exist`.  There are not many useful resources to solve this issue.  I tried different suggestions online, but in no vain.  Currently I am trying to add the JavaFX package to my Java directory.  But it doesn't work.

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded javafx-sdk-11.0.2 folder.  Inside the folder, there are 2 directories - legal and lib
2. Moved items in `legal` dir to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/legal`
3. Move items in `lib` dir to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib`
4. Reopen Terminal to compile this .java file.

Question_1: Did I miss anything above?

Question_2: If this approach is wrong, what would you suggest?

Comment: Why did you copy files? Did you try compiling with `--module-path` as [documented](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)?

Comment: Don’t add a library bigger than the JDK itself, when all you need, is just a `Pair` type. You can use `Map.entry(a, b)` instead, or `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`, if you need support for `null` or pre-Java 9 versions. Or any of the other 3rd party libraries providing a `Pair` type without the baggage of a UI library/webkit engine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`javafx.util.Pair` is part of the `javafx.base` [module](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/util/Pair.html), and as you have mentioned, you need to download the JavaFX SDK to your machine, as it is no longer part of the Java JDK anymore.

You can follow the [OpenJFX docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) on how you can get started.

Once you have [downloaded](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) the SDK, if you want to run JavaFX 11, you will see that you need to do something as [documented](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx):

```
export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX.java
java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX
```

This means that you run your Java 11 and include the modules from the JavaFX SDK independent location. Note that `javafx.controls` has as transitive dependencies the `javafx.base` and the `javafx.graphics` modules.

However, you won't read in those docs that you have to copy the JavaFX files into the JDK. That won't work.

The main reason why it won't work: Java 11 and JavaFX 11 are modular, and even if you see the JavaFX jars under `path/to/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib`, the JDK uses a big file: `/path/to/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/modules` to run the `java` command. That file was created when the JDK was built, therefore adding any jar to it won't have any effect.

**Alternative**

However, you will find in the docs the *right* way to "copy" the JavaFX SDK into the JDK: by creating a new custom image. See the [link](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular), section `Custom JDK+JavaFX image`.

> You can use `jlink` to create a runtime image that includes some or all the JavaFX modules, without being attached to a given project.

So you can create a combined image Java11+JavaFX11, and use that as your new JDK. This will allow you getting rid of the `--module-path` and `--add-modules` arguments (in terms of JavaFX at least).

In fact, some distributions like [this one](https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-11.0.2/) already do this.

So the options are: you use the regular JDK and the JavaFX SDK (with `--module-path` and `--add-modules`) or you create/use a custom JDK that includes JavaFX.

Comment: I got javac to work, but java gives "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"